# Excel, By clicking on Cell, the Focus is moved to another cell

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel, I want to have a cell (B10) that when clicking it, the focus will change to another cell (C12).

This other cell is defined in another Cell (A2).

Any Idea?

GorovDude

Answer (score 2):

Use worksheet_selectChange. In essence, the code will look like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = Range("B10").Address Then
        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = Range("A2")
        Range(rng.Value).Select
    End If
End Sub
```

I've hard-coded the range addresses for clarity.

Comment: Great, but how will i be able to make this code applicable for a full column?

Comment: If you would like to check if the user has clicked in a particular column, check whether the Intersect of the Target range and the column "is not nothing", rather than comparing the addresses.

Answer (score 2):

This code will cause Range(A2) to be selected whenever the user clicks in column B:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
 If Not Application.Intersect(Range("B:B"), Target) Is Nothing Then
 Range("A2").Select
 End If
End Sub
```